# Is it possible to spawn a random mob using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a button that when pushed, will spawn a random mob at a given `x y z` coordinates, but I can't seem to figure out how to pick a random mob.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a randomization system set up and then for each output have it use a certain mob. This means for each output you will have to hard-code a mob to go along with it. Your randomization can use scoreboard events, droppers (dropper will drop a random item out of its container), entity walking, `@r` with armor_stands, etc.